# When filling in the fields + active checkbox, we activate the button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a form with different fields and what I am trying is that the Submit button is not active until all the entries and the acceptance checkbox are filled and checked, in fact if an entry is removed afterwards the button is disabled again.

The point is that the inputs work correctly for me, but I can't get the checkbox to work properly, if I get it until I click on it and everything is full, the button doesn't get activated, but if I remove the box again , the button is still on.

My code:

```js
(function() {
        $('#infoEquipo > div > div > div > input, textarea').keyup(function() {
          $("#micheckbox334").on("click", function(){
    
            var empty = false;
            $('form > div > div > div > input, textarea').each(function() {
              if ($(this).val() == '' && $(this).is(":checked")){ // <- ambas deben cumplirse
                empty = true;
              }
            });
            if (empty) {
                $('#llamada223').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    
            } else {
                $('#llamada223').removeAttr('disabled');
            }
          });
         });
      })()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="infoEquipo" method="post" class="formInfo">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-6">
          <div class="separaInput">
            <i class="fas fa-user form-control-email2"></i>
            <input type="text" class="form-control myInput2" name="nombre" id="nombreLL" placeholder="Persona de contacto" required >
          </div>
          <div class="separaInput">
            <i class="fas fa-mobile-alt form-control-email2"></i>
            <input type="text" class="form-control myInput2" name="telefono" id="telefono" placeholder="Teléfono"required>
          </div>
          <div class="separaInput">
            <i class="fas fa-envelope form-control-email2"></i>
            <input type="text" class="form-control myInput2" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email"  required>
          </div>
          <div class="separaInput">
            <i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt form-control-email2"></i>
            <input type="text" class="form-control myInput2" name="ciudad" id="cuidad" placeholder="Ciudad" required>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-6">
          <div class="separaInput">
            <i class="fas fa-building form-control-email2"></i>
            <input type="text" class="form-control myInput2" name="centro" id="centro" placeholder="Nombre del centro" required>
          </div>
          <div class="separaInput" style="display:none;">
            <i class="fas fa-sign-in-alt form-control-email2"></i>
            <input type="text" class="form-control myInput2" name="equipo" id="equipo" value="<?php echo $encu['nombreEquipo'];?> <?php echo $encu['small'];?>">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group separaInput2">
          
            <textarea class="form-control myInput3" name="mensaje" id="mensaje" rows="5" required></textarea>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-12 center">
        <div class="">
          <input type="checkbox" class="micheckbox334" id="micheckbox334" style="display:inline-block;">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="mensajeResp" style="text-align:center" style="margin-bottom:2%;">

      </div>
      <button  type="submit" id="llamada223" class="btn btn-primary btnNews2 espacioEnvia" disabled="disabled">MÁS INFORMACIÓN</button>
    </form>
```

Comment: Can you put your HTML and Javascript on Snipped quickly? So that we can run the code and assist?

Comment: Ok give me a moment

Comment: you already have the snippet @MosiaThabo

Comment: cool, let me have a look quickly

Comment: you've seen? @MosiaThabo

Comment: yes, sorry man. I was having my Late Evening meal. But I have posted your answer... Sorry for the delay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this. I recommend using `.prop()` when you deal with html attributes, especially when you keep changing them conditionally.

```js
(function() {
  var button = $('#llamada223');
  var checkbox = $("#micheckbox334");
  var inputs = $('.text-input');
  
  function switchButton(state){
    if(state === "off"){
      button.prop('disabled', true);
    }else if(state === "on"){
      button.prop('disabled', false);
    }
  }
  
  function inputsAreField(){
    var input_are_filled = true;
    inputs.each(function(index, input){
      if( $(input).val() === undefined || 
          $(input).val() === '' || 
          !$(input).val()){
        input_are_filled = false;
      }
    });
    return input_are_filled;
  }
  
  checkbox.change(function(){
    if(inputsAreField() && checkbox.is(":checked")){
      switchButton("on");
    }else{
      switchButton("off");
    }
  });
  
  inputs.each(function(index,input){
    $(input).keyup(function(){
       if(inputsAreField() && checkbox.is(":checked")){
          switchButton("on");
          return;
        }
        switchButton("off");
     });
  });
})()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="infoEquipo" method="post" class="formInfo">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-6">
          <div class="separaInput">
            <i class="fas fa-user form-control-email2"></i>
            <input type="text" class="form-control text-input myInput2" name="nombre" id="nombreLL" placeholder="Persona de contacto" required >
          </div>
          <div class="separaInput">
            <i class="fas fa-mobile-alt form-control-email2"></i>
            <input type="text" class="form-control text-input myInput2" name="telefono" id="telefono" placeholder="Teléfono"required>
          </div>
          <div class="separaInput">
            <i class="fas fa-envelope form-control-email2"></i>
            <input type="text" class="form-control text-input myInput2" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email"  required>
          </div>
          <div class="separaInput">
            <i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt form-control-email2"></i>
            <input type="text" class="form-control text-input myInput2" name="ciudad" id="cuidad" placeholder="Ciudad" required>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-6">
          <div class="separaInput">
            <i class="fas fa-building form-control-email2"></i>
            <input type="text" class="form-control text-input myInput2" name="centro" id="centro" placeholder="Nombre del centro" required>
          </div>
          <div class="separaInput" style="display:none;">
            <i class="fas fa-sign-in-alt form-control-email2"></i>
            <input type="text" class="form-control text-input myInput2" name="equipo" id="equipo" value="<?php echo $encu['nombreEquipo'];?> <?php echo $encu['small'];?>">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group separaInput2">
          
            <textarea class="form-control text-input myInput3" name="mensaje" id="mensaje" rows="5" required></textarea>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-12 center">
        <div class="">
          <input type="checkbox" class="micheckbox334" id="micheckbox334" style="display:inline-block;">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="mensajeResp" style="text-align:center" style="margin-bottom:2%;">

      </div>
      <button  type="submit" id="llamada223" class="btn btn-primary btnNews2 espacioEnvia" disabled="disabled">MÁS INFORMACIÓN</button>
    </form>
```

Comment: Awesome Miguel, I am glad I could help. Good luck with everything! :)